# Timeline Slider using HTML CSS Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a timeline slider but I am very confused as I am a newbie.

Requirements:

1. It must have 15 items.
2. Two slider buttons(Left and right).
3. Display five weeks at one time.

How do I do this?

I am able to make the list but I don't know how to hide elements except the ones I want to display. How do I give width to each element of the list.

Comment: Sounds like you want carousel, I'd suggest looking for a basic tutorial on google and then see if you can add to it. Something like https://www.christianheilmann.com/2015/04/08/keeping-it-simple-coding-a-carousel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got what you want by using this code snippet for a simple slider: [Very Simple Slider](https://codepen.io/zuraizm/pen/vGDHl)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

   $('#checkbox').change(function(){
     setInterval(function () {
         moveRight();
     }, 3000);
   });
   
  var slideCount = $('#slider > ul > li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider > ul > li').width();
  var slideHeight = $('#slider > ul > li').height();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
  
  $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
  
  $('#slider > ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });
  
     $('#slider > ul > li:last-child').prependTo('#slider > ul');

     function moveLeft() {
         $('#slider > ul').animate({
             left: + slideWidth
         }, 200, function () {
             $('#slider > ul > li:last-child').prependTo('#slider > ul');
             $('#slider > ul').css('left', '');
         });
     };

     function moveRight() {
         $('#slider > ul').animate({
             left: - slideWidth
         }, 200, function () {
             $('#slider > ul > li:first-child').appendTo('#slider > ul');
             $('#slider > ul').css('left', '');
         });
     };

     $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
         moveLeft();
     });

     $('a.control_next').click(function () {
         moveRight();
     });

 });
```

```css
html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #58DDAF;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider > ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#slider ul ul li {
line-height: 3em;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed;
}

#slider ul ul {
    line-height: 1em;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">&gt;</a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev">&lt;</a>
  <ul>
    <li>
  <ul id="slide1">
   <li>Week 1</li>
   <li>Week 2</li>
   <li>Week 3</li>
   <li>Week 4</li>
   <li>Week 5</li>
  </ul>
    </li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">
  <ul id="slide2">
   <li>Week 6</li>
   <li>Week 7</li>
   <li>Week 8</li>
   <li>Week 9</li>
   <li>Week 10</li>
  </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
  <ul id="slide3">
   <li>Week 11</li>
   <li>Week 12</li>
   <li>Week 13</li>
   <li>Week 14</li>
   <li>Week 15</li>
  </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>  
</div>

<div class="slider_option">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox">Autoplay Slider</label>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
This is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of images let say you have list of 15 images and each image is inside a div that have class abcdclass then you can do some think like this as the code given. this will slide after 3 second.

```
<script>
                                $(function () {

                                    var slides = $(".abcdclass");
                                    var totalslides = slides.length - 1;
                                    var totalnumberofslides = slides.length - 1;

                                    setInterval(function () {

                                        var jsonCSS = {
                                            width: "0",
                                            opacity: "0",
                                            bottom: "0px",
                                        };

                                        $(".abcdclass").eq(totalslides).animate(jsonCSS, 2000);



                                        if (totalslides <= 0) {
                                            $(".abcdclass").animate({
                                                width: "100%",
                                                opacity: "1",
                                                height: "100%"
                                            }, 500);
                                            totalslides = totalnumberofslides;
                                        } else {
                                            totalslides--;
                                        }

                                    }, 3000);


                                });
                            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,I have gone through and used it. It works for me

https://codyhouse.co/demo/horizontal-timeline/index.html

Comment: Thank you!
This is a perfect place to look but a little difficult to understand.